# dlopen failed: library "libfbc.so" not found

Tags: java, android

I am getting this error with the code below. Not entirely sure on how to do it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private ArrayList<ClassProjects> Projects;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final ArrayList<ClassProjects> Projects = new ArrayList<>();
        final Button btnSave =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        final EditText MouldCode =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.MouldCodeEdtTxt);
        final EditText ProjectCode =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.ProjectCodeEdtTxt);
        final EditText ProjectName =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.ProjectNameEdtTxt);
        final TextView TextView =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        final Button btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);


        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


        Projects.add(new ClassProjects(ProjectCode.getText().toString(),MouldCode.getText().toString(),ProjectName.getText().toString()));



                File myFile = new File("test.txt");

                try (BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(myFile))){

                    for (int i=0; i<Projects.size(); i++){

                        TextView.setText(Projects.get(0).getmMouldCode());

                        br.write(Projects.get(i).getmMouldCode());

                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e){
                    TextView.setText("NOT SAVED");

                    System.out.println("notSaved");
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Error:

```
2019-08-07 10:48:27.586 3373-3373/oxley.it.machinemanagementsystem E/FBC: Can't load library: dlopen failed: library "libfbc.so" not found
2019-08-07 10:48:27.924 3373-3391/oxley.it.machinemanagementsystem E/OpenGLRenderer: Can't load library: dlopen failed: library "libfbc.so" not found
```

Comment: This has exactly nothing to do with `BufferedWriter`. NB You forgot to close it.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to write a `Projects.get(i).getmMouldCode()` data into your file, but the error is that `libfbc.so` can't be loaded. Firstly, in my limited experience in `Android：BufferWriter` have nothing to do with `libfbc.so`, I think you should locate the error your code about the Projects.add(new ClassProjects(ProjectCode.getText().toString(),MouldCode.getText().toString(),ProjectName.getText().toString())); Does this code segment has native method to call? Secondly,I think you must add filter into your `Logcat` at `Android Studio` ,I guess the error has no relatio

Comment: And nothing do with with [tag:bufferedreader] or [tag:android-studio] either. Don't tag indiscriminately, and specifically don't use an IDE tag just because you use that IDE. Use it when that's what the question is about.